# IBM IOT C# client thowing invalid ip address exception when constructing gatewayclient

Tags: watson-iot

I am beginning to use the sample IBM-IOT C# sample code as per
https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/iot-csharp/blob/master/docs/Gateway.rst

however I get "An invalid IP address was specified." thrown when the gateway constructor is called using the org id.

I'm using an orgid of 'p3wg4w' (set in config and accessed as a string property  Globals.WatsonOrgID" ) 
my code is

```
    private static void InitGatewayClient()
    {
        if (gw == null)
        {
            gw = new GatewayClient(Globals.WatsonOrgID,
                Globals.WatsonGatewayDeviceType,
                Globals.WatsonGatewayDeviceID,
                Globals.WatsonAuthMethod,
                Globals.WatsonToken);
            gw.commandCallback += processCommand;
            gw.errorCallback += processError;
            gw.connect();
            Console.WriteLine("Gateway connected");
            Console.WriteLine("publishing gateway events..");
        }
    }
```

Has anyone seen this before ?

Answer (score 1):

check if you can access or if you can: 
telnet p3wg4w.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com 8883

The libraries aren't using any IP to create the connection, it is using the below vars

public static string DOMAIN = ".messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com";
public static int MQTTS_PORT = 8883;

I can only think that your firewall is blocking the connection

I've used the below sample and worked just fine for me:

https://github.com/ibm-watson-iot/iot-csharp/blob/master/sample/Gateway/SampleGateway.cs

Comment: thanks for the sugestion,  I also built and ran the sample as a separate project. it works fine from our  site.    I'm actually trying to integrate this into an existing product , and I think there are some incompatibilities with runtime versions of some client libraries which are causing name resolution to fail.

Comment: if that gives you problem, then I guess you can give a try and use mqtt paho client 

https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/dotnet/

you can then just configure the mqtt client object to connect to the IBM Watson IoT Platform